# C++ PDB Symbols not loaded from same directory

Tags: c++, debugging, pdb-files

I have a c++ application that uses the g3log library to provide stack trace information when a crash happens. My release configuration also builds full pdb file so that this is possible. My app.exe stores the full path to the pdb file, that is I am not using /PDBALTPATH:%_PDB%.

When I am running the .exe from any folder path, so long as the .pdb has not been moved, then if I force a crash, I get a meaningfull stack trace. Now if I move the .pdb file to be in the same directory with my .exe it is not loaded anymore. My guess is that is does not match the path in the .exe. I thought that a .pdb file with the same name as the .exe would be loaded, I guess I was wrong.

I have tested by specifying /PDBALTPATH:%_PDB% such that there is no path information but then the .pdb file is again never loaded.

For both cases if I attach a debugger all is good in the debugger but not in my stack trace.

Is there a way to get the "automatic loading" of the .pdb (not sure how to call it) from when it matches the full path to happen when the .pdb is in the same directory. That way I can get a meaningful call stack when needed.

Comment: As I understand, you are trying to load PDB file without a debugger. And you want to log possible exception details by means of that library. Am I right?

Comment: That is correct and as I mentioned in my post that is already happening when the .pdb file path matches the one referenced inside the .exe. I just want it to happen also when the pdb is in the same folder somehow...

Answer (score 0):

In general, your use case seems pretty weird. Because unexpected exception usually means an undefined state, and there is no sense to continue. So you need probably to save a dump and investigate it later with your PDB files.

I'm not sure about the inner mechanics which gets the stack trace information in your dev environment. But usually, a **debugger is looking** for PDB files and trying to load it from different places. And when you place a PDB file with an EXE file, you make it possible to be found by a debugger.

For example, my build server saves PDB files while building to my local symbol server. And when I debug a crash dump with my debugger, it gets desired symbols correctly.

I have never tried to do things you are trying to do. In fact, it looks like debug build in production, which is not a good practice. So, I would consider an approach I described above.

Comment: It is possible in windows by using the dbghelp.dll. Then with the help of stacktrace64() function you can get the call stack for a process. Nothing special really that is how it is done. Of course that requires the pdb files so the stack trace is valid. So when an issue is found in production especially in places where remote access is not possible you can direct the customer to add the pdb files and get something useful in the log.

Comment: Yes, I know it is possible. Many years ago I used it for generating a dump for unhandled exceptions. But my point is to use dumps from users. Because of no need to publish big PDB files, get more information from dump files such as loaded modules, stack traces for all threads and so on. And you get a dump as soon as something bad happens. There is no need for the customer to put the PDB file and reproduce the actions. Some bugs are hard to reproduce.

Comment: Minidumps would be useful but there are cases where internet access is just not possible in various places. Contrary, a generated log file can be easily sent after the fact and said places are OK with text files rather than connecting to outside servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this path;
set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=C:\MySymbols, where your pdb files are there.
Thats the simple way, if you cant set this path, then follow below procedure.

You mentioned:

> > *When I am running the .exe from any folder path, so long as the .pdb has not been moved, then if I force a crash, I get a meaningfull stack trace.* <<

So, always make sure your app runs from the directory where the .exe+.pdb files are there.

You can do that with GetModuleFileName+SetCurrentDirectory.
That means, your working directory is different.
I would suggest is, in you application, get "[GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx)".
Then change the working directory to exe path using: [SetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I will give the setting of the path a try to see if it makes a difference. However, the problem here is that the pdb path is hardcoded inside the .exe file. It is visible if you open it with any text editor. While I could change the path of the exe what I need to "fake" is the path of the pdb. It's that one that has to match whatever is hardcoded in the .exe.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that @prasad-mk is half way correct. Setting the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH somehow forced my .pdb symbol to be loaded as in the case where the path matches.

Another option that I found is by using this utility 
http://bytepointer.com/tools/index.htm#peupdate to update the path to wharever the location of my pdb is.